# How to generate a list of PASS url's in varnishlog?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to generate a simple list of url's that get a 'PASS' from Varnish. varnishlog is a great utility, but it appears that it can't do this task, as it primarily logs HITS, and has no tag for PASS.

Any idea if there is a way to log this? Perhaps in vcl_pass subroutine?

Comment: Your question is misleading: you have several kind of "pass", and the one you're seeking seems to be the number of "fetch" instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I got it.

varnishlog -b -k 5000 -i TxURL